# In which project should Uno.Material be installed?

Tags: uno-platform

Should [Uno.Material](https://github.com/unoplatform/Uno.Material) be installed in `MyApp.UWP` only? Or all the projects in the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uno.Material should be installed in all your projects in the solution, as described in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/unoplatform/Uno.Material/issues/431#issuecomment-720190928).